¿por que me marca como error al momento de agregar las librerias de google maps 2024?
estoy tratando de agregar las etiquetas que son dos implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0' y implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0' y me marca error alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?todavia no agrego la api
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.gms.play.services.maps)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

}


buenas michh. Es necesario que proveas todo lo que puede ser relevarte para resolver el problema.
sin saber el error que genera, donde y en que condiciones, no es posible ayudarte
